# How to rename yii\web\YiiAsset filename

Tags: yii2, assets

I'm using Yii2 Framework, I don't know how to rename filename from `yii\web\YiiAsset`.
yii automatically generate this file on `web/assets` folder. It's possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can override `yii\web\AssetManager::hash($path)`

```php
class MyAssetManager extends yii\web\AssetManager{
    protected function ($path) {
        return hash('md4', $path);
    }
}
```

also, you can set `$hashCallback`, [read this](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-assetmanager#$hashCallback-detail)

you can rename asset files on aftercopy:

```php
'assetManager' => [
    'forceCopy'  => true,
    'afterCopy' => function ($from, $to) {
        if (basename($from) == 'site.css') {
            rename($to, dirname($to) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'newname.css');
        }
    },
],
```

or use "mysite.css" instead of "site.css" using [assetMap](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-assetmanager#$assetMap-detail):

```php
'assetManager' => [
    'assetMap'   => [
        'site.css' => 'mysite.css',
    ],
],
```

if none of the above is a solution to your problem, you will have to override `AssetManager->publishDirectory($src, $options)`, which ends up calling `FileHelper::copyDirectory` by default.

Comment: sorry, my question is rename filename (yii.js, yii.validation.js and yii.activeform.js) to something e.g (yii.js to be framework.js), not the folder name